# ArrayList a cannot be resolved

Tags: java, arrays

I have an ArrayList called `a`, but I am getting the error `"ArrayList a cannot be resolved"`. Why is it showing an error? This is my code:

```
package testscripts;

public class ExecutableLeadTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("D:\\LeadSuite.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook b = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        Sheet s = (Sheet) b.getSheet("Teststeps");
        Iterator itr = s.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Row rowitr = (Row) itr.next();
            Iterator cellitr = rowitr.cellIterator();
            while (cellitr.hasNext()) {
                Cell celldata = (Cell) cellitr.next();
            }
        }
        Cell Celldata;
        switch (Celldata.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                a.add(Celldata.getStringCellValue());
                break;
        }
    }

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            if (a.get(i).equals("KOHILA")) {
                System.out.println(a.get(i));
                System.out.println(a.get(i + 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: format your code, and then try to debug and see what might be wrong. I'm sure u'll figure it out on your own.

Comment: Format your code properly and count your { } brackets - you will see why...

Comment: The for loop is not inside the main() method

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop is not inside the `main()` method, but instead it is inside an instance initializer. At the same time, `a` is defined inside the `main()` method. The scope is different, so the `for` loop cannot reference `a` variable.

Move the loop inside the `main()` method.